Apps Script not stopping on last row of data of Google Sheet from submitted Google Form
I'm creating an Apps Script for a Google Form that when submitted will generate a Google Doc and send the URL link of the Google Doc to the recipient for editing purposes.
The trigger works. It does what it's intended to do as it creates the document and sends the email with the URL in it.
The problem is that it continues going through the google sheet and goes to the last empty cels and creates a blank Google Doc and the error message:
Error   Exception: Invalid email:
at unknown function
at onFormSubmit(Code:12:8)
which causes the whole process to stop. I know the error appears because there is no email in the last row of the Google Sheet because its all empty.
Here's the code:
const SHEETID = '1dplvx-LF5AhL4P-DgMGyqeW3z6VqeZJZmtyK-S_Uy6E'
const DOCID = '1oDFRGcajSJ66lZPYJ0EjxS3d9spS7TCPiRRVUciHvk0'
const FOLDERID = '1CjMmQ8p4q4O5aWjiAMyfe4VTCD2wJwZv'

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEETID).getSheetByName('Reference');
  const temp = DriveApp.getFileById(DOCID);
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDERID);

  const data = sheet.getRange("A:P").getValues();
  const rows = data.slice(2);
  rows.forEach((row,index)=>{
    if(row[15] == ''){
    const file = temp.makeCopy(folder);
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    const body = doc.getBody();
    data[0].forEach((heading,i)=>{
      const header1 = heading.toUpperCase();
        body.replaceText(`{${header1}}`,row[i]);
    })
    doc.setName(row[0]+' '+'-'+' '+row[3]);
    const docUrl = doc.getUrl();
    doc.saveAndClose();

    const email = row[2];
    const email2 = row[9];
    const subject = row[0]+' '+'-'+' '+row[3]+' '+'created';
    const messageBody = `Hi, ${row[7]}, <p> ${row[0]+' '+'-'+' '+row[3]} has been created. <p> Here is the link: ${docUrl} <p> Please wait for Approval Signature before you serve the file to the employee. <p> Thank you!`;
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to:email+','+email2,
      subject:subject,
      htmlBody:messageBody,
    });
    
    const tempo = sheet.getRange(index+3,16,1,1)
    tempo.setValue(new Date());
    Logger.log(row);
    }
  })
}


Though I've set a
if(row[15] == ''){ 

at line 13 and
const tempo = sheet.getRange(index+3,16,1,1)
tempo.setValue(new Date());
Logger.log(row);

at line 35, it still continues to generate the google doc for the next blank line.
Is there a way to get only the last response submitted to generate the document and send it as an email?
I think it will eliminate the  if(row[15] == ''){ and const tempo but I haven't found the answer to this for a while now.
Any help is invaluable.


 rows.forEach((row,index)=>{


Since you are processing form responses individually as they are submitted, you do not need to iterate the rows in the Reference tab.
Use the event object to discover the values the user submitted, like this:
  // rows.forEach((row,index)=>{ <-- commented out
  const row = e.values;
  if (row[15] == '') {
    const file = temp.makeCopy(folder);
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    const body = doc.getBody();
    data[0].forEach((heading, i) => {
      const header1 = heading.toUpperCase();
      body.replaceText(`{${header1}}`, row[i]);
    })
    // ...


Changed it to that but it gave a new error.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')
at onFormSubmit(Code:12:17)
I think because I did not assign values for e.values?
Also, what do I do with the
const rows = data.slice(2);
As the function of rows will be gone when I remove the rows.forEach((row,index)=>{

The code is designed to run on a trigger when a form response is submitted. In that context, the event object e is properly populated.
Do not run the code through the ▷ Run button in the script editor. If you do, the event parameter e is not populated, causing the error you mention.

"what do I do with the const rows = data.slice(2)" You only need that if you have inserted two unneeded rows in the header of the form responses tab. If you have not inserted rows, you can remove the slice().
